# Date time issue on new web server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

We have recently moved to a new web server. Old web server has Windows Server 2008 R2, the new web server has Windows Server 2012 R2. The database tables and data has been moved over, all columns remain the same.

The issue is when testing the login page of the site. It works perfectly on the old web server, however on the new server we get this error :

```
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.
```

There is obviously an issue with the new version of SQL Server, because the code is the same :

```
Dim strStartTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")

Dim strConnx As String = "Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=TEST;User Id=user;Password=password;"
        Dim cmdx As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Insert into [LoginLog]([LogDate], [Consultant], [BU])VALUES (@LogDate, @Consultant, @BU)", New SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConnx))
        cmdx.Connection.Open()
        cmdx.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogDate", strStartTime)
        cmdx.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Consultant", txtUserName.Text)
        cmdx.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BU", Session("BU"))
        cmdx.ExecuteScalar()
        cmdx.Connection.Close()
```

We have tried various options(setting date format on SQL server as well as the web server, however that does not resolve it - Pls assist, thanks

Comment: did you tried  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")

Comment: the region settings are different between the old and the new server. Best option is to switch to ISO-8601 format (yyyymmdd)

Answer (score 2):

It's not an issue with the server. The fact that it didn't show up on the other server just means that you were lucky. NEVER create a `String` to represent data that isn't actually text unless it's for the purposes of display or serialisation.  In this case, you start with a .NET `DateTime` and you want to send it to a SQL Server `datetime` column.  There should NOT be a any text anywhere in between.  DO NOT do this:

```
Dim strStartTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
```

That is your problem right there.  If you want to round the `DateTime` to the nearest minute then do that:

```
Dim currentTime = Date.Now
Dim startTime = currentTime.Date.AddHours(currentTime.Hours).AddMinutes(currentTime.Minutes)
```

You then use that binary `DateTime` value as your parameter value.  No conversion means no conversion issues.

Comment: I probably should point out that it actually could have worked if you had done this: `Dim strStartTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")`. That's the format you should be using when, for instance, writing a date literal in SSMS. You probably fell foul of one server using day-first as the standard date format and the other using month-first. To be clear though, that is NOT an issue with the server. Both servers will work fine if you write code properly.